# Mocha unit tests for Firebase app

Tags: javascript, firebase, mocha.js, firebase-authentication

I use firebase 3.3.0 and I want to use [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) function in my mocha unit test, but I get error **auth/network-request-failed**

```
Unhandled rejection Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

**test.js**

```
const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDdA1POUWy9eid1AdBYuMdxch_k8ob7Qrg",
    authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com",
};

const FIREBASE_API_REF = firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);

before(function (done) {

        promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            return FIREBASE_API_REF.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(firstUserEmail, firstUserPassword)
            .then(function (userData) {
                firstUserId = userData.uid;
                resolve(userData);
                done();
            }, function (error) {
                return reject(error);
            })
        });

    });
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --grep ./e2e.js --invert --compilers js:babel-register -R spec --ui bdd --timeout 7000"
  }
```

Comment: You will need to show to what `FIREBASE_API_REF` refers. Also, there are other problems with the code: `done` is never called; `resolve` is never called; and you don't need to create your own promise - that's an [antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: @cartant thanks for response, this is not complete part of `before` function. I just wanted to show piece of code where I cannot call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function. Please see my edited question.

Comment: I think that part of the problem with the question is that it's not clear what you are asking and you have snipped out parts of the test code - where are the `describe` and `it` calls? Also, you have not specified how you are running the tests: in a browser using Karma; or in Node using the mocha command?

Comment: @cartant I run tests using mocha command (I added this script to my original post). `describe` and `it` are not important if I get error `before` function. I don't understand what is not clear in my question. I showed a piece of code where I get error in firebase function and I don't know why.

Comment: The problem is that it's very simple to write a working test that takes your config and hits your Firebase instance - so there is something else happening in your code. And your question is still not clear, as no one will know what `AccessStore.setCredentials(userData.uid, userData.cd);` does. And without being able to see the surrounding `describe` and `it` blocks how can anyone be sure that the test you have in your question is even the one that's failing?

Comment: Sorry that is redundant as well. I tried to run the test and it works now, but i have no idea why..

Comment: have you tried to `.catch((err) => done(err))` the error from the auth before then?

Comment: [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/pejalo/53fa075ef0e873431b606d322dcfadd5) is working for me and might be helpful for you to compare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say, ***"I want to use signInWithEmailAndPassword function in my mocha unit test"*** then I would say to you, "why"?

Are you trying to help out the Firebase team by testing that their authentication service works? That's nice of you, but if you want to test YOUR app then you should **NOT** be calling out to firebase at all in a unit test. What you really want to check is that a response similar to what Firebase responds with is handled correctly by your application in the code that is run once the response comes back.

If I were tasked with writing a test for this I would use the sinon library with mocha and create a stub that calls a different function which returns some data instead of actually calling to Firebase:

*This illustrates the syntax for a sinon stub:*

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);
```

*This is what I would do in your example:*

```
var stub = sinon.stub(FIREBASE_API_REF.auth(), "signInWithEmailAndPassword"
,  () => { 

  // Simply return a JSON object that is similar to the normal response from Firebase
  return {
    name: "Jim",
    data: {
      something: "some stuff"
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Jim - I'm thinking how to use mocha test with the database for testing firebase security rules. It would be really useful to have access to logged in user for that.

Comment: Hmm you could do something like an integration test to verify security rules independent of your front-end ui. In your "happy case" test, login with a dummy user account, try to access database object, and assert that you can get the object. You can then make another test that logs in as a dummy user who doesn't have access. For him you can assert that that request for DB object was denied (either it returns null or request fails, etc.). Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

probably you don tneed it anymore, but instead of create a stub i just used spyOn and it worked like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else facing this problem, I was able to determine the problem came from the global `XMLHttpRequest` object from jsdom. I was able to get rid of the error by using this code for setting my global variables:

```js
var doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = doc.defaultView;

for (var key in window) {
  if (!window.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  if (key in global) continue;
  if (key == 'XMLHttpRequest') continue;

  global[key] = window[key];
}
```